# Running multiple Databricks queries with golang client

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I am using github.com/databricks/databricks-sql-go to connect and run queries on my Databricks warehouse. However when I try to run multiple queries:

```
insert into....;
insert into....;
```

It fails and complains on syntax errors.

```
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'INSERT'...
```

Is there a config to enable running multiple queries like that.
Example of how Snowflake are doing it: https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/master/multistatement_test.go